# Applying a function to a nested list successively, and after each application of the function, the list is nested one less time

Tags: r

I have a nested list comprised of data frames. Each data frame has the same structure.

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df3 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df4 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df5 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df6 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df7 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df8 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df9 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df10 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df11 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df12 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df13 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df14 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df15 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df16 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df17 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df18 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df19 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df20 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df21 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df22 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df23 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df24 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df25 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df26 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df27 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
list1 <- list(list(list(df1, df2, df3), list(df4, df5, df6), list(df7, df8, df9)), list(list(df10, df11, df12), list(df13, df14, df15), list(df16, df17, df18)), list(list(df19, df20, df21), list(df22, df23, df24), list(df25, df26, df27)))
```

First, I will calculate column means.

```
list1 <- lapply(list1, function (x) {
  lapply(x, function (y) {
    lapply(y, colMeans)
  })
})
```

Then, I will row bind the data frames within each list element.

```
list2 <- lapply(list1, function (x) {
  lapply(x, function (y) {
    do.call(rbind, y)
  })
})
```

Notice that now the list is one less level nested. After I do this, I will again calculate column means for each data frame, but now, the data frames are nested one level less than they were originally.

```
list2 <- lapply(list2, function (x) {
  lapply(x, colMeans)
})
```

After I perform that operation, I will again row bind these data frames within the list.

```
list3 <- lapply(list2, function (x) {
  do.call(rbind, x)
})
```

I will continue this pattern until I end up with a final data frame.

```
list3 <- lapply(list3, colMeans)
final_df <- do.call(rbind, list3)
```

Is there a way to automate this by writing a function to first row bind and then calculate column means? I have to do this many times. I am wondering if I can find a function that will operate successively on a list that is nested one less time each step.

Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to automate here. Do you want to go from `list1` to `final_df` directly?

Comment: Yes. I just updated my question, so hopefully it makes a little more sense now. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help in your case but you can use `sapply(list1, function(x) mean(unlist(sapply(x, function(x) Filter(is.numeric, x)))))` which gives the same output as `final_df` but in a vector form.

Comment: That works in this case, but if my original list is nested many more levels, I would have to continue to nest `sapply` functions as you've done here. I'm hoping to find a way to do this without re-writing one of the apply functions each time.

Comment: `sapply(list1, function(x) mean(as.numeric(unlist(x)), na.rm = TRUE))` which returns the output with a warning.

Comment: Just curious, do you realize that the *unweighted* `mean` of previously-calculated means can be a biased summary statistic? Since there *are* unequal counts of these `col1` variables, you're losing significance.

Comment: @r2evans - yes; this is just an example.

Comment: Continuing that point (I understand your point of a simplified problem), would your real data have *problems* with doing a recursive-bind and then doing an aggregate summary after that step?

Comment: @r2evans - I'm sorry; I don't understand what you mean!

Comment: Okay ... what you're suggesting is "summarize then bind", what I'm suggesting is "bind then summarize". Does the `colMeans` step (which fails with `LETTERS`, btw) have to happen with each individual deeply-nested frame, or can it be done one one much-much-longer frame?

Comment: For this particular problem, it needs to happen within each deeply-nested data frame, unfortunately.

Comment: @r2evans - actually, I just realized it can be done on one long data frame. To get there, the row binding step would still need to be done iteratively, though, right?

Comment: DavidMoore, my previous (now un-deleted) question solves the problem of recursive-binding, after which you can do your aggregation. Does that help any?

Comment: @r2evans - yes - I hadn't thought to use a recursive function like this! That's brilliant. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive function might work well. Though `do.call(rbind, ...)` technically does it, I find `dplyr::bind_rows` or `data.table::rbindlist` to be more robust.

Reproducible random data:

```r
set.seed(42)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df3 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df4 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df5 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df6 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df7 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df8 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df9 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
list1 <- list(list(df1, df2, df3), list(df4, df5, df6), list(df7, df8, df9))
```

Execution:

```r
recurse_rbind <- function(x) {
  islist <- sapply(x, is.list)
  x_notlist <- bind_rows(x[!islist])
  x_islist <- bind_rows(lapply(x[islist], recurse_rbind))
  bind_rows(list(x_notlist, x_islist))
}

out <- recurse_rbind(list1)
nrow(out)
# [1] 90
head(out)
#   col1        col2
# 1    Q -0.09465904
# 2    E  2.01842371
# 3    A -0.06271410
# 4    J  1.30486965
# 5    D  2.28664539
# 6    R -1.38886070
tail(out)
#    col1         col2
# 85    G -1.551544822
# 86    I  1.167169549
# 87    U -0.273645701
# 88    C -0.467845325
# 89    R -1.238252328
# 90    O -0.007762034
```

Comment: I'm sorry my original question was somewhat confusing! I just updated it, so hopefully it's clearer now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the desired result is because there is no sample output in the question, the code given in the question gives an error and the general case is not clear; however, this recursively walks the structure taking means and may be what you are looking for or if not could be modified appropriately. Perhaps the rbind should be cbind and/or the cbind should be rbind.

```
Mean <- function(x) { is.num <- sapply(x, is.numeric); colMeans(x[is.num]) }

walk <- function(x) {
  if (is.data.frame(x[[1]])) as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(x, Mean)))
  else Mean(do.call("cbind", lapply(x, walk)))
}

walk(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R solution:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df3 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df4 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df5 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df6 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df7 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df8 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df9 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df10 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df11 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df12 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df13 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df14 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df15 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df16 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df17 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df18 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df19 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df20 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df21 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df22 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df23 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df24 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df25 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df26 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df27 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10), col2 = rnorm(10))
list1 <- list(list(list(df1, df2, df3), list(df4, df5, df6), list(df7, df8, df9)), list(list(df10, df11, df12), list(df13, df14, df15), list(df16, df17, df18)), list(list(df19, df20, df21), list(df22, df23, df24), list(df25, df26, df27)))
fxn1 <- function (x) {
  if (all(sapply(x, is.data.frame))) {
    colMeans(do.call(rbind, x))
  } else if (all(sapply(x, is.list))) {
    colMeans(do.call(rbind, lapply(x, fxn1)))
  }
}
fxn1(list1)
```